# In AS3/AIR how can I execute the result method of a responder object?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

We are creating an extension for the NetConnection object. When we get an error we will retry “n” times. After “n” times we want to call the responder result method returning an error. The responder object contains two properties, both functions, however we cannot seem to see how to access those functions. Is it possible to execute the “result” function of Responder object?

An example might be;

```
_rspResponder:Responder = new Responder(someFunction);

// lots of code...

_rspResponder.result("Error: Connection timeout failure.\n A network connection error occurred, if needed please try to save work and restart the application.\n Otherwise just restart the application.\n");
```

Edit:

Based on comments below I created an extended responder like;

```
package com.fluorinefx
{
    import flash.net.Responder;
    
    public class PublicResponder extends Responder
    {
        /**
         * result - Result handler function
         *
         * @return result
         */
        private var _result:Function = null;
        public function get result():Function
        {
            return this._result;
        }
        
        public function set result(value:Function):void
        {
            this._result = value;
        }
        
        /**
         * status - Status (error) handler function
         *
         * @return status
         */
        private var _status:Function = null;
        public function get status():Function
        {
            return this._status;
        }
        
        public function set status(value:Function):void
        {
            this._status = value;
        }
        
        public function PublicResponder(result:Function, status:Function=null)
        {
            _result = _result;
            _status = status;
            super(result, status);
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to use it in my extended NetConnection like;

```
import com.fluorinefx.PublicResponder;
private var _rspResponder:PublicResponder;
public override function call(strCommand:String, rspResponder:Responder, ...parameters:Array):void
_rspResponder = rspResponder;
```

I get an implicit coercion error on the "_rspResponder = rspResponder;" line.

Comment: The **Responder** itself does not seem to allow accessing its **result** and **status** handlers directly. You need some wrapper code for this. To keep the handlers in an accessible way and to count the number of network failures.

Comment: I have an existing codebase with hundreds of "NetConnection" calls. I would like to avoid modifying all of those "NetConnection" calls to call "MyResponder" (a wrapper).

Comment: So, basically, subclass **Responder** with the custom class then find/replace **new Responder** with **new SmartResponder** (or whatever you call it) all over your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

> After “n” times we want to call the responder `result` method returning an error.
> Is it possible to execute the `result` function of the Responder object?

Does something like this setup help you?

```
//# global vars
public var _rspResponder :Responder;
public var try_count :int = 0;

//# test it...
_rspResponder = new Responder( onResult, onError );

//# Since "result" param can be Object or String... using asterix to allow any data-type
private function onResult( result:* ) :void
{
     trace( result ); try_count = 0;
}

//# no comment needed here... 
private function onError( error:Object ) :void 
{
    try_count++;
    _rspResponder = new Responder( onResult, onError ); //# retry again
    
    //# after N retries, send custom error String to "onResult" function
    if ( try_count == 5) 
    {
        onResult( "Error: Connection timeout failure.\n A network connection error occurred, if needed please try to save work and restart the application.\n Otherwise just restart the application.\n" ); 
    }
}
```